# Python Tkinter adjusting button size to window size

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter, trying to do a GUI for myself.

My question is: 
Is it possible to adjust a buttons size on a grid according to the window size?

For example: 
My window is small so I want my button to be small, but if I drag the window and make it bigger, than the button will get bigger too.

Any good suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  Use the grid manager, give your widget a `sticky`.  Then use `grid_columnconfigure` to give the column (or `grid_rowconfigure` for the row) an expansion weight.

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
b=Button(root,text="Push Me")
b.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=E+W)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
```

you can find out more here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: What about `y` axis?

Comment: @Nouman  you would use `sticky=N+S` and `root.grid_rowconfigure()`